# NGINX order GET parameters alphabetically

Tags: php, nginx, parameters, get

We have a production site which runs Nginx and WordPress. I pass this request to the wp-admin/load_styles.php-file:

```
wp-admin/load-styles.php
    ?c=0
    &dir=ltr
    &load%5B%5D=dashicons,admin-bar,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menus,wp-pointer,widgets
    &load%5B%5D=,site-icon,l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check
    &ver=4.9.8
```

Now, when I output the `$_SERVER` variables I see the following:

```
[QUERY_STRING] => 
    c=0
    &dir=ltr
    &load%5B%5D=,site-icon,l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check
    &load%5B%5D=dashicons,admin-bar,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menus,wp-pointer,widgets
    &ver=4.9.8
```

As you can see, the two elements in the `load[]`-array have switched places (because Nginx or something else on the server sorts the parameters alphabetically). In load_styles.php, the load-array is concatenated. That leads to this string for load:

> ,site-icon,l10n,buttons,wp-auth-checkdashicons,admin-bar,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menus,wp-pointer,widgets

instead of

> dashicons,admin-bar,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menus,wp-pointer,widgets,site-icon,l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check

This in turn leads to the wp-auth-check and dashicons never being loaded.

I cannot hack the way these styles are loaded, so I am wondering if anyone knows of a setting in Nginx where I can turn off alphabetic sorting of GET-parameters.

- Is it NGINX that sorts the parameters alphabetically before passing them to PHP?
- Why oh why?
- How do I turn it off? It messes up an array which is sent though GET-parameters in a specific order which cannot be messed with.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that, perhaps a setting specific to your server? Depending on the order seems a bit of a fragile solution though.

Comment: If you want to send an array, why not just use the array syntax? If you send `a[0]=1&a[1]=2&a[2]=3`, you'll have an array you can use from PHP in `$_GET['a']`

Comment: I'd say that if your parameters need to be in a particular order, you should be using path parameters (e.g. `/test/1/2`) instead of a query string. There's nothing in the HTTP spec that requires a webserver to parse and forward a query-string in the order it was submitted.

Comment: Are you using a PHP framework on that server or anything else that might interact with the routing, other than NGINX?

Comment: I strongly suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). There shouldn't be any reason for the query string to be ordered. What is the code in question doing?

Comment: I have updated the question. I thought I was smart, simplifying my question. Apparently, I was wrong :)